# Spring data mongodb: How to define cursor limit in findAll method

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am working with spring data mongodb geospatial criteria, my requirement is that i have to find users using item's coordinates and radius. When admin will add item,it will work on users which fulfills criteria. So for now,i am using mongotemplate's findAll method. but in future,users may be upto `50000`,so i think `findAll` is not efficient for it. i am looking for limit set in findAll or any alternate method to do it in spring data mongodb.

My query is

```
List<User> users = mongoTemplate.find(
                new Query(Criteria.where("address.coordinates").within(
                        new Circle(longitude, latitude, radius))), User.class);
```

Please suggest me how can i use cursor limit in findall method.

I am trying to do using

```
DBCollection collection = mongo.getDB(envConfiguration.getDBName())
                .getCollection("Users");
        DBCursor cursor = collection.find();
        cursor.limit(1000);
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }
```

But now problem is that how i will use geospatial query in this which i mentioned in example.

Thannks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `skip` and `limit` methods offered by `Query`, like this:

```
List<User> users = mongoTemplate
                .find(new Query(Criteria.where("address.coordinates")
                        .within(new Circle(longitude, latitude, radius)))
                        .limit(1000), 
                        User.class);
```

You can also use a `with(Pageable pageable)` method and last but not least you can use **Mongo Repositories** and their `findAll(Pageable pageable)` method.

Comment: I know about limit and skip,but how they will work in background jobs ?